# Fluxbox shortcut to open an xterm, or switch to an existing one

Tags: scripting, keyboard-shortcuts, fluxbox

Is it possible using fluxbox to setup up a shortkey to say <kbd>winkey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> that opens up a terminal (say `xterm` or whatever) with these properties:

1. If there is already a terminal that the working directory is = ~ and it is not currently running a command (i.e. its at the prompt) then show that one.
2. Or if not create a new terminal

Comment: Is your shell `bash`, `zsh`, or something else?

Comment: I suggested changing the title because I don't think the question is specific to Fluxbox.  No harm leaving it in the tags or the question tho.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I'd do it:

1. make your shell set the title to "bash" when at the prompt, and the name of the command when it runs a command, or anything so you can tell them apart
2. create a script that calls `wmctrl` to list open windows, then:

   - if `wmctrl` finds a window with a title of "bash", raise it
   - else start an `xterm`
3. use `xbindkeys` to call that script when you press your shortcut

---

**making your shell set the window title when you run a command**

Here's a simplified version of how I do it in bash.  I haven't double checked the code, but it works on my machine.

```
# set the title when we run a command
setcommandhook()
{
    if $has_debug_trap
    then
        trap 'command=$BASH_COMMAND; eval settitle "\"${title}\""; trap - DEBUG' DEBUG
    fi
}

# set the xterm title
settitle()
{
    printf "\033]0;$*\007"
}

promptstring='$(hostname):$(pwd)$ '
title='$(hostname) "${command:-$0}"'

# prompt and window title
if test -n "${title}"
then
    PROMPT_COMMAND='command=; eval settitle "\"${title}\""'
    if $has_debug_trap
    then
        PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND; setcommandhook"
    fi
fi
if test -n "${promptstring}"
then
    PS1='$(eval echo -n "\"${promptstring}\"")'
fi
```

Doing it in `zsh` is easier, because it has the `preexec` hook.

You can see [my shell configs](http://svn.mikelward.com/svn/conf/) for more details, e.g. the `getcommand` function which handles commands like `fg` in a nicer way.

---

**raising the xterm that has a bash prompt otherwise starting a new one**

Write a script that uses `wmctrl -l` to list windows, looking for one with `bash` in the title.  If one is found, then run `wmctrl -i -a <id returned by wmctrl -l>` to raise it, else just call `xterm`.

Here is a script that does it:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# bashprompt
#
# if there is an xterm open at a bash prompt, raise/focus that window
# if there isn't start a new xterm
#
# requires that your xterm window title has "bash" at the end
# when there is no command running and doesn't have "bash" at the end
# when a command is running
#
# see <http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6842> for more details
#
# Mikel Ward <mikel@mikelward.com>

# change this to whatever is unique about your window title
# (i.e. a string that appears in the title when the shell is at a prompt
#  but does not appear when running a command)
prompttitle="bash$"
terminalprog="xterm"

if ! type wmctrl >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "wmctrl can't be found, please install it" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

if ! output="$(wmctrl -l)"; then
    echo "Error running wmctrl -l" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $prompttitle ]]; then
        id=${line%% *}
        break
    fi
done <<EOF
$output
EOF

if test -n "$id"; then
    wmctrl -i -a "$id"
else
    "$terminalprog"&
fi
```

Or [download it from my scripts repository](http://svn.mikelward.com/svn/scripts/bashprompt).

---

**running the script when you press Win+R**

Assuming your script is called `/usr/local/bin/bashprompt`, make a file `~/.xbindkeysrc` containing:

```
"/usr/local/bin/bashprompt"
    Mod4 + r
```

then run `xbindkeys`.  Add it to your `.Xclients` file or similar to make it start up automatically.

Comment: I wrote the `bashprompt` script.  You should now have everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

`fluxbox` can match windows based upon certain patterns on its own. With at least `fluxbox-1.1.1` this is possible:

```
  Mod4 r :If {Some Matches (title=.*bash) (class=XTerm)} {NextWindow (xterm)} {Exec xterm}
```

(translates to: `on press windows-key + r: check, if there is a xterm with its title ending in 'bash'. if there is, go to that window; if not, open a new one`. With a bleeding edge version (git) you can even go to windows on a different workspace.

The only thing you have to do is to modify the title (or any other property of the window carrying the bash)  depending on what you do. if you look at the prompt you have to set a property, if you launch a command, you have to take away that property. `fluxbox` is not able to look inside the applications, it only knows about the windows.

Comment: +1 Shorter than mine, but of course you'd still need to use my `.bashrc` above.